# Using python logging module to info messages to one file and err to another file

Tags: python, file, logging

I've found some similar example to log messages to multiple files. But nothing quite for what I want. I am using the logging module and I am logging all info messages to the console and a file. (I will turn off the console logging at a later date).

However I wish to expand this to log all info messages to file.log and all error messages to file.err. Even better if its possible to log all messages to file.log (error and info) and then all err messages to a separate file.

Is this possible?

## ---------

I can't answer my own question for 7 hours apparently, so I'll just update my original question.

## ---------

I feel stupid now. After several hours trying examples before posting I found this 'again'.
Its like the task of typing out what I was trying to do triggered something when reading the examples.

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

This outputs everything at INFO level and above to one log file (log_file) and then also prints logging.error and logging.warning messages to a separate file (err_file)

```
# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                   format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                   filemode='w')

log_error = logging.FileHandler(err_file)
log_error.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

log_info = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
log_info.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')    

# tell the handler to use this format
log_error.setFormatter(formatter)    
log_info.setFormatter(formatter)        

# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(log_info)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(log_error)
```

Comment: could you perhaps share some of your code?

Comment: Then WHAT ? Are you proposing a solution ? Then write below as an answer. Are you adding some points to our question ? If yes please explain what is the interest of our code as I don't understand what do you want...

Comment: The question is valid, however OP has solved it within the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**test_log.py:**

```
import logging

def get_logger(    
        LOG_FORMAT     = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        LOG_NAME       = '',
        LOG_FILE_INFO  = 'file.log',
        LOG_FILE_ERROR = 'file.err'):

    log           = logging.getLogger(LOG_NAME)
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

    # comment this to suppress console output
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    log.addHandler(stream_handler)

    file_handler_info = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_INFO, mode='w')
    file_handler_info.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    file_handler_info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(file_handler_info)

    file_handler_error = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_ERROR, mode='w')
    file_handler_error.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    file_handler_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    log.addHandler(file_handler_error)

    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return log

def main():

    my_logger = get_logger()

    my_logger.info('This is an INFO message')
    my_logger.warning('This is a WARNING message')
    my_logger.error('This is an ERROR message')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
$ python test_log.py
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         INFO     This is an INFO message
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         WARNING  This is a WARNING message
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         ERROR    This is an ERROR message

$ cat file.log
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         INFO     This is an INFO message
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         WARNING  This is a WARNING message
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         ERROR    This is an ERROR message

$ cat file.err
2013-09-20 11:52:07,096 root         ERROR    This is an ERROR message
```

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to plug [Filter](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/logging.html#filter-objects), a nice example to filter only one level is available [here](http://streamhacker.com/2010/04/08/python-logging-filters/):

```
import logging

class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno == logging.INFO
```

Then `Filter` object can be used on `Handler` with method [`Handler.addFilter(filt)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.addFilter)